# Is it possible to have a [String: Any] array in a Firestore document?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've encountered an issue where I'm getting a SIGABRT error with this title:

`Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x7fff87afce38) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff87afb628)`

Essentially, I was trying to retrieve a list of tasks from my Firestore database. The database is structured as follows:

```
lists {
    <autoID from Firebase> {
        "name": String
        "users": [String]
        "tasks": [
                     ["name": String,            // This is the first task in the array
                      "description": String,
                      "due": Date
                      "delegate": Int
                      "status": Bool
                     ]
                     ["name": String,            // This is the second task in the array
                      "description": String,
                      "due": Date
                      "delegate": Int
                      "status": Bool
                     ]
                 ]
        "completed": [[]]                       // Possible to have the same structure as "tasks"?
    }
}
```

In my code, I created a query which attempts to filter the name of the list and the user's UID. However, when trying to save `tasks` into a variable, the SIGABRT occurs stating the above issue. The following is my code:

```
struct Task {

    var name: String
    var description: String
    var due: Date
    var delegate: Int
    var status: Bool

}
```

```
let listsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("lists")
listsReference.whereField("users", arrayContains: uid).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

if let error = error {              
    // Error exists. errorAlert is created, prompting the user to attempt refreshing their app to load once again.

    let errorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "An error occurred.", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    errorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in }))
    self.present(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        for document in snapshot!.documents {    

            let data = document.data()

            if data["name"] as! String == self.titleName {

                let tasks = data["tasks"] as! [NSDictionary]            // SIGABRT error occurs here.

                self.listField.text = (data["name"] as! String)
                self.documentID = document.documentID

                for task in tasks {

                    let date = task.value(forKey: "due") as! Timestamp
                    self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
                    self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
                    self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

                    self.tasks.append(Task(name: task.value(forKey: "name") as! String, description: task.value(forKey: "description") as! String, due: date.dateValue(), delegate: task.value(forKey: "delegate") as! Int, status: task.value(forKey: "status") as! Bool))
                    self.tasksTable.reloadData()

            }

        }

    }

}
```

What can I do to work around this issue? Also, are there any optimizations I can make to this structure (since I'll have to find a way to append to this `tasks` array in the database). Does anyone know how to update the `tasks` array in the future?

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post.  It sounds like dealing with the crash is the first, most important thing.  Please leave questions about optimizations and other questions for later posts.

Comment: There are a few ways to approach this but... questions: You've got a users var set up as an array of Strings and then theres a task var that has tasks but none of that seems to be related to each other. How do you know which task goes with which user? What's the correlation between that data? Secondly go Swift with Dictionary ([String: Any]), not NSDictionary - however, casting anything to a dictionary looses ordering so that may be an issue. But then your iterating over that dictionary when you could have just iterated over the tasks directly. Can you clarify what you're doing and asking?